# how to create an alias to a complicated generic type in Java?

Tags: java, syntax, types, alias

I have this code:

```
Callable<Map<String, List<com.w.automation.rtsimulator.headlessclient.data.SearchResult>>> callable = new
                Callable<Map<String, List<com.w.automation.rtsimulator.headlessclient.data.SearchResult>>>() {
            @Override
            public Map<String, List<com.w.automation.rtsimulator.headlessclient.data.SearchResult>> call() throws
                    Exception {
                Map<String, List<com.w.automation.rtsimulator.headlessclient.data.SearchResult>> searchResults =
                        Foo());
                return searchResults;
            }
        };
```

how can I shorten the type `Map<String, List<com.w.automation.rtsimulator.headlessclient.data.SearchResult>>`

to be syntactically sugar shorter?

**Edit**

I want to make it even shorter. how can I alias it to type "MyClass"

Comment: why dont you import "com.w.automation.rtsimulator.headlessclient.data" package ?

Comment: `import com.w.automation.rtsimulator.headlessclient.data.SearchResult`?

Comment: You could start by `import`ing `com.w.automation.rtsimulator.headlessclient.data.SearchResult`; also, what Java version is it? If 7, you can just `new Callable<>()` etc

Comment: I want to make it even shorter. how can I alias it to type "MyClass" ?

Comment: Well, then, use Guava and its `Multimap`; you'll have a nice `Callable<Multimap<String, SearchResult>>` ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
import com.w.automation.rtsimulator.headlessclient.data.SearchResult;

Callable<MyClass> callable = new Callable<MyClass>() {
    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public MyClass call() throws Exception {
        return (MyClass) Foo();
    }
};
```

You'll also need to define MyClass:

```
public class MyClass extends Map<String, List<SearchResult>> {
    // implement whatever code you want here for your class objects
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create clases that wrap those types and work with them:

```
class WrapClass {
    Callable<Map<String, List<com.w.automation.rtsimulator.headlessclient.data.SearchResult>>>     callable;
etc...
```

Comment: not good enough as I have `public Map<String, List<com.w.automation.rtsimulator. ..`

Answer (score 0):

```
import com.w.automation.rtsimulator.headlessclient.data.SearchResult;

Callable<Map<String, List<SearchResult>>> callable = new
    Callable<>() { // this works from Java 7
            @Override
            public Map<String, List<SearchResult>> call() throws Exception {
                return Foo();
            }
    };
```

Comment: I want to make it even shorter. how can I alias it to type "MyClass"  ?

Comment: You can't create an alias to a type in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Really unclear what you really want, but you can declare, for instance:

```
public final class MyClass
    implements Callable<Map<String, List<SearchResult>>>
{
    // Instance variables, constructor(s) and stuff

    @Override
    public Map<String, List<SearchResult>> call()
        throws SomeException // <-- DO NOT throw Exception
    {
        // implementation
    }
}
```